# Locationlistener and Timers

Tags: android

Does anyone know why i'm not able to get any coordinates when registeren a locationlistener via a Timertask (tried both NETWORK_PROVIDER and GPS_PROVIDER)
but when i register them manually i get coordinates just fine.

this is how i register my listener:

```
Looper.myLooper().prepare();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
Looper.myLooper().loop();
```

my location listener looks like this:

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        lat = location.getLatitude();
        longt = location.getLongitude();
        if(lat !=0 && longt!=0)
        {Log.e(LOG_TAG, "getting coords");
            locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "got coords!!!", 2000).show();
            reqlat.add(String.valueOf(lat));
            reqlon.add(String.valueOf(longt));
            DateFormat timeformat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            Date now = new Date();
            Date date = new Date();
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
            reqtime.add(String.valueOf(timeformat.format(now)));
            reqdate.add(String.valueOf(dateFormat.format(date)));  
            savemyData();
            lastlongt = longt;
            lastlat = lat;
            logging=false;
            coords = false;
            CancelGpsTimer();
            Looper.myLooper().quit();

        }

    }
```

i suspect it has something to do with the looper.prepare() but i can't figure out what. If i don't have a looper.prepare() i get an exception saying i can't create a handler insisde a thread that has not called looper.prepare().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it comes from the fact that you quit the loop. You should try to execute the loop until you receive the coordinates and then quit.

[Looper API Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html)

Comment: i tried moving the quit(), but it doesn't work
if i use gps provider the icon just keeps blinking,
if i use network provider nothing happens at all. 

the on locationchanged is never called

Comment: Do you execute Looper.loop() ?

Comment: no, is that needed in addition to something, og instead of something?

Comment: To be able to handle messages (Handlers) with your thread (The LocationManager uses a handler internally), you need to have a message loop associated to your thread executing the code.

Right now, you are just preparing the loop but not executing it (not looping) so your thread cannot manipulate messages.

What you have to do is:

Prepare the loop
Request Location update
Run the loop

In your locationChanged method, quit the loop if you don't need anymore to get coordinates.

Comment: i tried that, but when the locationchanged method is never called, nor is the loop();

updated the question with new code, did i misplace something?

Comment: Yes, you have to call `Looper.myLooper().loop();` just after requesting the update of the location (in your first block of code) and not the in the `onLocationChanged` method.

`onLocationChanged` can be called only if the thread having called the location update is running the message loop, or in your current implementation, you try to run this loop in the handler itself.





`Looper.myLooper().prepare();
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0,locationListener);
Looper.myLooper().loop();`